# Why mirror modifier material not work

Tags: materials, mirror

I have a mirror modifier and applied material on it. Why i cant see same material on the other side.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume because the mirrored mesh doesn't really have vertex position in the memory(just fake), something that the generated node needs. you can see the only green side of the mirror to left.

[image]

but you can use the mapping node and move it.

[image]

UPDATE: just for sake of testing I came up with something. there's no real reason of why I did what I did, just experimented.
you can adjust the amount of the mirrored part by shrinking or fattening the "bell" shape in the vector curves node. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply. My question is i want to flip all my material as seen in the right hand should be flip on left hand.

Comment: have you tried to move it with the mapping node? not sure if that will work for your case but more than that I don't think you could actually use the generated node for this scenario.

Comment: i have unwrap and set node to uv also but the black disappear from it only yellow remains. Any other solution how it works

Comment: I've update my answer with a possible solution using the generated node. the texture get's mirrored but it may behave differently depending on the mesh I guess